# Garden path sentence en français

Tags: grammaire, anglais, syntaxe

L'expression anglaise "[garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence)" désigne des phrases qui sont initialement analysées à la lecture d'une certaine façon qui s'avère être incorrecte quelques mots plus tard, de sorte qu'il faut revenir en arrière et analyser à nouveau. Par exemple : "The horse raced past the barn fell.", d'abord comprise avec "raced" comme verbe prinicpal, jusqu'à "fell", où on est obligé de réanalyser "raced past the barn" comme une relative.

Y a-t-il une expression française qui correspond à "garden path sentence", et quels sont les exemples les plus connus de garden path sentences en français ?

Comment: Le concept est assez spécifique à l'anglais. La plupart des *garden paths sentences* contiennent deux mots qui peuvent être soit un verbe soit un nom ou un adjectif. Dans la plupart des autres langues indo-européennes ou finno-ougriennes, les verbes ont des terminaisons qui rendent l'ambiguïté beaucoup plus rare, au moins à l'écrit.

Comment: Exemple en Français : « La petite ferme, lentement mais sûrement construite dans la vallée ». On peut faire plus simple mais les adverbes préservent la surprise. C'est une adaptation de la célèbre ambiguë « la petite ferme le voile ».

Comment: Gilles: Certes, le français s'y prête moins, mais ça doit bien être possible d'en faire, tout de même ? Evpok: J'avais pensé à procéder comme ça mais je ne trouve pas que les résultats en partant de ces phrases ambiguës sont si convaincants...

Comment: Si on part d'une phrase ambiguë pour ne lever l'ambiguïté qu'à la fin en confirmant la plus inattendue des interprétations, on pourrait avoir un effet similaire: *«L'oiseau vola tout en douceur au bord de la fenêtre le diamant qui y était déposé.»*

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr** : le concept s'applique mal au français.

Exemples :

> L'invité qu'il a dit des folies.
>
> Il y a autant d'étudiants à l'examen que j'ai corrigé de copies au partiel.

---

Il n'y a pas d'expression française équivalente, parce que le phénomène est beaucoup plus rare qu'en anglais (par exemple, moins de mots peuvent être à la fois des noms et des verbes).

Je propose ***phrase amenée en bateau*** comme traduction créative (avec ambiguité sur *à mener*).

Il n'y a pas d'exemple canonique. On peut en construire à partir de phrases notoirement ambiguës, en désambiguisant à la fin de la phrase. Par exemple :

> La petite ferme lentement mais sûrement construite dans la vallée.
>
> Je ne veux pas d’avocat, Julie m'en a déjà vendu un.
>
> Sylvain a vu un homme avec un télescope, qu'il a ensuite ramené chez lui pour lui demander conseil.
>
> Elle regarda l'homme, le vit dans toute sa splendeur, et estima qu'il était un peu plus grand que la moyenne, environ quinze centimètres.

---

<sub>[Une source](http://www.semantique-gdr.net/dico/index.php/Ambigu%C3%AFt%C3%A9), et merci Gilles et Evpok. [Une autre.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=993085)</sub>

Comment: « le vit dans toute sa splendeur » mérite un +1 à lui tout seul.

Comment: En fait seul le premier et le troisième example présentent une ambiguïté syntaxique (le premier est d'ailleurs particulièrement vache parce qu'on commence à le lire comme il faut, puis on quand on voit « lentement » on est convaincu qu'on a pas lu comme il fallait, et on pense à « une petite » qui ferme, et finalement on se rend compte que la première lecture était la bonne…) Les autres exemples ce sont des ambigüités sémantiques et ça n'a pas vraiment grand chose à voir avec des garden paths.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: le dernier est syntaxique aussi, même s'il ne change qu'un sous arbre et pas la structure de la phrase entière. Pour le concept de garden path, je n'ai pas l'impression que l'ambiguïté doive nécéssairement être syntaxique, il suffit que le lecteur soit induit dans une compréhension érronée qu'il lui faut réviser après d'autres mots. Je pense que la deuxième phrase fait ça.

Comment: Si j'ai eu besoin d'un moment pour comprendre la première phrase, la deuxième (avec les étudiants) ne m'a pas du tout fait l'effet "garden path", j'ai tout de suite compris le sens de la phrase, et je vois pas quelle autre interprétation on pourrait faire du début de la phrase. (En tout cas bien trouvé pour la première ^^)

Answer (score 4):

[*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&srchtxt=GARDEN%20PATH%20SENTENCE) recense une source pour « *phrase trompe l'oeil* » (Rady, M. 1983. *L'ambiguité du langage naturel est-elle la source du non-determinisme des procédures de traitement*, Thèse de doctorat, París 6, 259p.). Voir aussi au *GDT* (« [*phrase trompe l'oeil*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17014586) », 1997).

Comment: +1 pour cette découverte

Answer (score 2):

Je ne connais pas d'équivalent courant en français. Le plus proche peut être une [ambigüité syntaxique](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigu%C3%AFt%C3%A9#Ambigu.C3.AFt.C3.A9_syntaxique) travaillée de façon œ avoir une chute qui lève le doute.

Pour reprendre l'exemple de Wikipédia:

> Elle emporte la clé de la maison au garage puis l'insère dans le cadenas de son antivol.

Answer (score 0):

Je ne connais pas d'expression française semblable.  Mais comprenez que cette expression en anglais n'est possible que grâce à l'idiome « *take someone down the garden path* ».  Le concept d'une telle phrase doit exister en toute langue, mais il n'y a pas forcement un mot ou une expression associée.

Il se pourrait qu'il y ait un idiome similaire en français, et peut-être une expression dérivée et abrégée comparable à « garden path sentence », mais les chances pour les deux — surtout le deuxième — sont minimes.

Si vous ne cherchez pas une telle association (idiome similaire ⟺ expression) mais juste un terme pour le concept, c'est possible.  Mais je n'en connais pas.

Ne cherchez surtout pas du cote des jardins...  Si vous trouvez une expression comparable elle n'aura rien à voir avec un parcours de jardin, j'en suis persuadé.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse ! Je cherche juste un terme pour le concept, pas un qui fasse nécessairement référence à une expression qui soit un calque de l'expression anglaise que vous mentionnez.

Comment: Certains psycholinguistes utilisent le terme *impasse syntaxique* (p.e. [1](http://archive-ouverte.unige.ch/unige:1425/ATTACHMENT01), [2](http://www.academia.edu/6000686/Larchitecture_des_processus_de_production_et_de_r%C3%A9ception_aspects_neuro_psycholinguistiques_J._Fran%C3%A7ois_et_J.L._Nespoulous_)).

Answer (score 0):

Peut-être que l'on pourrait gloser l'expression et traduire par "une phrase qui vous mène en bateau jusqu'à ce qu'on arrive à sa chute". Ce n'est pas idéal, mais c'est à peu près l'idée en gardant une expression imagée. Sinon, on pourrait dire qu'il s'agit d'une phrase qui se comprend / se construit à rebours.

En revanche, je ne trouve aucun exemple du même type en anglais.