# Pourquoi certaines suites de sons trompent-elles notre découpage (à l'oreille) des mots ?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, linguistique, jeux

Lisez l'extrait suivant :

> « Tes laitues naissent-elles ? Si tes laitues naissent, mes navets naîtront. »

Aucun problème.
La structure est très simple, l'enchainement est logique, aucun mot étrange ou sophistiqué<sup>1</sup>.

Or, et c'est un petit jeu auquel je me souviens m'être livré de temps en temps au gré des occasions depuis mon adolescence quand j'ai entendu cette phrase la première fois, **personne ne la comprend oralement**.

Pour préciser, j'entends par là que depuis que je fais ce petit jeu-test<sup>2</sup>, personne ne l'entend correctement à la première audition. Il me faut toujours de nombreuses répétitions, voire une explication finale avec découpage très ralenti mot par mot, pour que les uns et les autres finissent par réussir à "entendre" la phrase.

Je vais faire un parallèle avec l'informatique pour les (probablement nombreux) informaticiens d'entre vous, mais il semble que c'est une de ces phrases qui "font planter le parseur". Notre oreille à l'habitude de découper le flot presque ininterrompu de sons en mots, mais là elle tombe sur un os, et je ne sais pas pourquoi.

**Des avis ? Qui saurait m'expliquer les véritables causes de l'inaudibilité de cette phrase ?**

---

<sup>1</sup> on pourrait y déceler, à l'extrême limite, une petite impropreté lexicale, dans la mesure où on attend pas la "naissance" de légumes, mais admettons que le parallèle est assez largement évident.
<sup>2</sup> à noter pour le test : l'élocution doit être suffisamment rapide, mais sans excès

Comment: Je pense que tu négliges trop l'aspect sémantique. On ne s'attend pas à ce que des laitues ou des navets naissent, donc cette interprétation a du mal à percer. As-tu fait l'expérience avec une phrase plus idiomatique, par exemple « Tes laitues poussent-elles ? » ? Il serait aussi intéressant de comparer des citadins pour qui la laitue est un nom singulier qu'on met dans son assiette et des ruraux pour qui les laitues au pluriel sont des plantes qu'on cultive.

Comment: @Gilles Oui, je l'ai noté, c'est une part de l'explication, mais elle ne suffit vraisemblablement pas. Je veux dire que si cela suffisait, on ne comprendrait aucune phrase hors contexte. Notre oreille est capable de saisir correctement, dès la première écoute, la plupart des phrases, même infiniment plus loufoques que mon exemple.

Comment: @Amphiteóth Tu dis "on ne s'attend pas à ce qu'on parle de nos légumes, en ville..." mais dans le contexte d'un mini-jeu de langage comme celui-ci, l'autre est prévenu qu'il va entendre une phrase-jeu (donc supposément insolite ou particulière), il s'attend un peu à tout. Personne n'aura besoin d'une seconde écoute pour comprendre "Un camion-benne aux airs de spationaute regarde la Joconde en skiant hors piste." Même loin des pistes ;-)

Comment: Essayez celle ci :
"Dinno dinât dit-on du dos d'un dodu dindon" Enjoy ;)

Comment: La version que je connaissais est légèrement différente... *Didon dînat, dit-on, du haut d'un dodu dindon.* mais il y a effectivement une filiation entre ces jeux sur les sonorités. L'exemple que tu cites est plus basé sur l'allittération, comme *Si six scies scient six cyprès, six cent six scies scient six cent six cyprès.*

Comment: La pie niche haut, l'oie niche bas, l'hibou niche ni haut, ni bas. Où l'hibou niche? Réponse: l'hibou niche ni haut ni bas.

Answer (score 3):

*Avertissement* : la réponse dévoile le jeu de mots.

---

Bien un peu comme avec la phrase [*trompe-l'oeil*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13623), on a ici la phrase [*trompe-oreilles*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trompe-oreilles) :

> Un trompe-oreilles est une phrase difficile à comprendre, souvent
> formée de monosyllabes, qui donne l’impression d’être en langue
> étrangère ou d’avoir une autre signification.

On trouve des variantes dans l'article, par exemple :

> – Tes laitues naissent-elles, Estelle ?
> – Oui, mes laitues
> naissent.
>  – Si tes laitues naissent, mes laitues naîtront.
>
> – Sous un arbre, vos laitues naissent-elles ? (On comprend : « Sous un
> arbre volait une Estelle »)
>  – Si vos laitues naissent, vos navets
> aussi naissent !
>
> [ *Wikipédia* - « trompe-oreilles » ]

On remarque la confusion avec un nom de personne (dans la question, « *telle est une Estelle* ») et la possibilité de construire la phrase avec le verbe plus usuel au lieu du légume comme sujet (vos laitues/volait une) surtout si on a déjà le complément de lieu.

Personnellement je trouve le « *télétunestel* » insolite ou exotique; et je forme facilement « *télé*(vision) » avec les sons. Et je ne suis pas étonné de voir dans l'article une référence à *François Pérusse* ("Ressemble à du latin : « Alevasesquidistus » - [François Pérusse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_P%C3%A9russe)"). Enfin, ça m'a été présenté davantage dans le contexte d'un jeu de construction où on ajoute des « blocs » (similairement à d'autres tours que j'ai déjà par exemple observés en chanson) :

> – Tes laitues naissent-elles ?
>  – Oui mes laitues naissent.
>  –
> Tes laitues naissent-elles là ?
>  – Oui mes laitues naissent là
> ?
>  – Là où tes laitues naissent, tes laitues naissent-elles bien
> ?
>  – Oui là où mes laitues naissent, mes laitues naissent
> bien.
>  etc.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse, j'ignorais surtout qu'il y avait un terme spécifique. Car il me semble bien au final que c'est la conjonction de plusieurs caractéristiques spécifiques qui produit l'effet saisissant. Notamment, le fait que les couples de sons formés par la fin de certains mots avec le début de leur suivant suggèrent "malheureusement" des sortes de pièges, sémantiquement plus probables mais trompeurs.

Answer (score 3):

Cette phrase peut être plus ou moins difficile à comprendre selon la quantité de pièges qui y figurent et les libertés que l'on prend avec la prononciation.

Dans la version que je connaissais, par exemple, on disait :

Au pied de cet arbre, vos laitues naissent-elles ? Si vos laitues naissent, tels navets naîtront.

Avec les **liaisons**, la prononciation de "vos laitues naissent-elles?" est identique à celle de "volait une Estelle" (c'est ce que l'on appelle une holorime). Un "Estelle" qui vole n'a pas beaucoup de sens, mais la phrase est prise en dehors de son contexte. Or "volait" est un terme plus "courant" que "laitue", donc on s'accroche au premier mot que l'on identifie et on essaie de donner du sens à la suite. De même, "une" est un mot très courant alors que relativement peu de mots se terminent par le son "u" (la liaison est donc très rare). C'est donc la présence d'un grand nombre de liaisons peu fréquentes qui rend la phrase difficile à décortiquer, un peu comme dans une version latine (teteroromamanunudadatetelalatete).

La prononciation sert ensuite (volontairement ou non), à guider l'auditeur sur la mauvaise voie. D'une part, en marquant un minuscule temps d'arrêt entre lait-uesnaissent. D'autre part en n'accentuant pas la forme interrogative (si on insistait sur l'interrogation, la présence du "elles" en fin de phrase serait plus facile à interpréter). Une grosse partie du piège vient donc de la prononciation.

En parlant rapidement et grâce aux liaisons, "tes laitues naissent-elles" se prononce comme "telle est une Estelle!". Ici aussi, l'intonation interrogative devrait aider à faire le découpage, mais hors contexte c'est difficile vu que l'"Estelle"(élément le plus incongru) n'arrive qu'en fin de phrase. Les phrases qui débutent par "tel est" sont toutefois assez rares, donc on glisse moins facilement dans ce piège.

Comment: Il faut avouer que oui, c'est encore pire de dire *vos laitues* plutôt que *tes laitues*. Et tu as raison à propos des "minuscules points d'arrêt", ils sont d'autant plus trompeurs que discrets, et c'est une part non négligeable de la difficulté.

Comment: +1 aussi pour holorime

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas un mythe, mais un exercice que certains francophones adorent : jouer sur les mots, jouer avec les mots, de leur sonorité, du rythme qui les relie, des confusions possibles et souvent salaces, de juxtapositions sonores qui peuvent avoir plusieurs graphies... bref du rapport de l'oral (vécu à un moment, dans un contexte) et de l'écrit (cadavre de l'oral qui capte l'esprit de celle ou de celui qui lui redonne vie par son souffle).

Beaucoup d'exercices de diction utilisent ce genre d'exercice pour exercer la musicalité, travailler sur les multiples prononciations possibles, sur l'intonation, l'intention ...

Toute sentence, interrogation dite hors contexte (en dehors de ce que l'auditeur peut s'attendre à entendre) amènera une 'relecture mentale', une décomposition phonétique pour assembler les phonèmes audibles entre eux, qui par la malice du locuteur, se trouvera n'être pas celle que ce dernier à mentalement formulé par écrit.

Ce qui indique que ce genre de test n'a de valeur qu'aux yeux de celui qui le conçoit, de plus il ne fonctionne qu'une fois ; après l'autre rentre dans le jeu (certains se lassent rapidement) ou vous tourne le dos.

Le grand oracle *[Oulipo](http://oulipo.net/)* usera du *[naphtalène](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naphtal%C3%A8ne)* contre les mythes de votre question.

Comment: Belle réponse. Effectivement, il y a une part non négligeable de jeu, de poésie, et d'humour dans ces chaines de mots. Je pense par exemple au *Dis, à m'aimer, consens, va !* de Bobby Lapointe...

Comment: (et à propos du naphtalène : c'est malheureusement impossible tant que les anglais rencontreront de la viande avec les allemands)

Answer (score 1):

Tout le secret de ce genre de phrase en français, est ce qui rend le français comparable à une musique. On peut jouer lié ou détaché. Le français est une langue liée. Chaque mot, en principe, s'emboîte dans le suivant.
ça perturbe énormément ceux qui apprennent le français! Et ça donne peut-être un petit charme supplémentaire à la langue. Les mystères du français. Une langue qui est capable de transformer ses mots, pour qu'ils sonnent mieux!

Si le français était une langue où on détache clairement les mots, "Tes laitues naissent elles", serait plus clairement audible, mais beaucoup moins euphonique.

Comment: Est-ce réellement une particularité du français ? Si oui, je l'ignorais, mais c'est intéressant. J'avoue que je serais curieux de savoir quelles langues séparent réellement (perceptiblement) les mots en parlant. N'est-il pas attendu que des personnes peu familières avec une langue, quelle qu'elle soit, aient du mal à détacher les mots dans le flot verbal qu'ils entendent ?