# « (Faire) sa fête à (la dignité de) quelqu'un » : ellipse du verbe, extension de sens à la caractéristique de la personne ?

Tags: usage, locutions, possessif, figure-de-style, ellipse

Il existe une expression familière, populaire ou argotique, *faire sa fête à quelqu'un*, par antiphrase, signifiant *malmener physiquement ou moralement* quelqu'un ([Larousse en ligne](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/f%C3%AAte/33431/locution?q=faire%20sa%20f%C3%AAte#171846), [Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/f%C3%AAte) ; var. *souhaiter, ça va être* [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/f%C3%AAte)).

> Leur fête aux enfants migrants.
>  Sa fête à la dignité des enfants migrants.

On aurait dans ces deux exemples l'expression en question avec ellipse du verbe (*faire*) et avec un désir de construire une phrase un peu [*trompe l’œil*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13623) (dans un titre par exemple), et dans le deuxième une extension du sens à une caractéristique indélébile de l'être humain (sa *dignité*, il irait sans dire), peut-être par métonymie. Est-ce compréhensible ?

---

- L'ellipse du verbe faire est-elle comprise, est-elle inusitée avec cette locution ?
- La locution se comprend-elle encore quand
  on l'étend à l'attribut de la personne plutôt qu'à la personne
  nommément et dans ce cas a-t-on une hésitation avec le pronom ici ; est-ce inusité ?

Answer (score 1):

L'ellipse de *faire* est inusitée et ferait perdre le sens de l'expression.

Comment: Pour le deuxième point, avec l'expression sans ellipse, est-ce qu'on l'a déjà vue avec autre chose que la personne directement, comme avec _dignité_ ou _droits de_ cette personne ? Je vois sur internet des trucs comme faire sa fête... avec des inanimés : à la musique, à la science, à la bourse, à la fiction etc. mais ça semble être parfois l'antiphrase de l'antiphrase. Une idée ? Merci !

Comment: Oui, on rencontre bien l'expression avec des inanimés, mais le sens est alors à ma connaissance toujours positif. Une expression intéressante grammaticalement parlant est «Je vais te lui faire sa fête à la musique…» [Tribune de Genève](https://www.tdg.ch/culture/fete-musique-25-ans-fausse-note/story/27248387).

Comment: _Faussement vindicatif_ pour celle-là dit-on... Ouais la tournure _je vais te lui_ je la trouve usuelle à l'oral, comme dans _m'en vas t'i en donner une.._, mais le _te_ n'est pas obligatoire, c'est une variante plus familière je crois, ou parfois ça aide à l'élocution d'avoir une particule etc. Merci !